# What can I use to repair a crack in a plastic AC Condenser Drip pan?

Tags: repair, air-conditioning, waterproofing, patch

I've currently got an oldish furnace (early '90s Lennox), with an A/C system.  The blower motor burnt up on me last week, and I just had it replaced.  It turns out that the reason for the motor going, was that my AC condenser drip pan has a crack in it, and water was dripping down into the blower housing, rather than draining properly.

The drip pan is plastic, and is molded to the condenser.  So the only way to replace the pan, is to replace the condenser.  Unfortunately, the AC is an R22 system, and after calling near and wide, with the R22 phaseout there are no replacement condensers anywhere.  So to fix a cracked pan, I'd have to replace the entire A/C system.

This got me to thinking- I can access the crack in the pan easily.  Since it is simply a pan to divert water, would it be reasonable to simply patch/waterproof the crack?  If so, what would I patch it with?  Would a quality epoxy work?  A fiberglass patch?  Any ideas on how I might be able to fix this, without dropping thousands of dollars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track - a strong, waterproof epoxy and a piece of rigid plastic or fiberglass should seal that crack nicely.